# Hide/remove columns from servicestack requestlogger page

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to hide or remove columns from the request logs page (RequestLogger plugin) in ServiceStack?

The **Form Data** and **Items** columns are never going to be useful for us so displaying them just wastes unnecessary screen real estate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a copy of the built-in [InMemoryRollingRequestLogger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/InMemoryRollingRequestLogger.cs) and modify it to suit your needs and then register to use it with:

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature {
    RequestLogger = new MyRequestLogger()
});
```